# networkx combine lists of edges to clusters

Tags: python, graph, cluster-analysis, networkx, edges

I have three lists of edges:

1. a = [(2, 1), (3, 2), (9, 3), (10, 9), (11, 10)]
2. b = [(2, 1), (3, 2), (9, 3), (10, 9), (11, 10)]
3. c = [(2, 1), (3, 2), (10, 3), (11, 10), (1, 9)]

The end goal is I need to cluster these edges into clusters. In this specific case, there is only one cluster:

a and b edges are the same and in c edges (1, 9) and (10, 3) are new with respect to a and b. However, 1 is connected to 9 indirectly in both a and b and 10 is connected to 3 indirectly as well. The end result should be cluster 0: [1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 11]

If I had lists of:

1. a = [(2, 1), (3, 2), (9, 3), (10, 9), (11, 10), (50, 100)]
2. b = [(2, 1), (3, 2), (9, 3), (10, 9), (11, 10), (50, 100)]
3. c = [(2, 1), (3, 2), (10, 3), (11, 10), (1, 22), (50, 100)]

The end result should be cluster 0: [1, 2, 3, 10, 11] and 1: [50, 100]. 22 should not be included at all because it is not possible to reach 22 from 1 indirectly in a and b.

I tried implementing this with networkx:

```
def get_final_clusters(graph):
    components = (graph.subgraph(c) for c in nx.connected_components(graph))
    comp_dict = {idx: comp.nodes() for idx, comp in enumerate(components)}

    return comp_dict

def update_graph(G, edges_set):
    for edge in edges_set:
        if G.has_edge(edge[0], edge[1]):
             G[edge[0]][edge[1]]['weight'] += 1
        else:
             G.add_edge(edge[0], edge[1], weight=1)


def build_graph(edges_set):
    G = nx.Graph()

    for edge in edges_set:
        G.add_edge(edge[0], edge[1], weight=1)

    return G

g = build_graph(a)
update_graph(g, b)
update_graph(g, c)
edges_to_keep = keep_edges_with_weight_3(g)
final_g = build_graph(edges_to_keep)
clusters = get_final_clusters(final_g)
```

With respect to the first three list of edges, I noticed that above solution is incorrect because edges like **(1, 9)** and **(10, 3)** and **(9, 3)** would have weight less than **3**. Then I tried changing **update_graph** function to such that it would have a check once unseen edge is detected if it is possible to reach one node from the edge from another node of the edge indirectly and then update weights based on that. However, I failed. I was wondering if anyone knows how to update the function **update_graph** to get the desired result.

Just a note the functions above would work if I could make list of edges bigger. Instead of a = [(2, 1), (3, 2), (9, 3), (10, 9), (11, 10)] to have a = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 9), (1, 10), (1, 11), (2, 3), (2, 9), (2, 10), (2, 11), (3, 9), (3, 10), (3, 11), (9, 10), (9, 11), (10, 11)] and so on, but this is not allowed due to additional space used.

Comment: Can you provide the code for `keep_edges_with_weight_3`, too?

Comment: Also, for the second graph, the first cluster should not include node 9, since it is not present in list c, correct?

Answer (score 0):

To determine whether a node n can be part of the solution,
the node needs to be a member of each of the three lists of
edges. All edges connecting nodes from the list created by
this definition need to be kept. This is implemented below
in the routine `keep_edges_mine`.

To help with that, I have added labeling to the nodes to
indicate which lists they were from.

The edges do not have to have a weight of 3. For comparison,
I've written a routine `keep_edges_with_weight_3`. In the
first graph, this routine fails to keep node 9 in the
solution.

Also, there is not much functional difference between
functions `build_graph` and `update_graph`, so I removed
`build_graph`.

This leads to the following implementation:

```
import networkx as nx

def get_final_clusters(graph):
    components = (graph.subgraph(c) for c in nx.connected_components(graph))
    comp_dict = {idx: comp.nodes() for idx, comp in enumerate(components)}
    return comp_dict

def update_graph(G, edges_set, label):
    for edge in edges_set:
        if G.has_edge(edge[0], edge[1]):
            G[edge[0]][edge[1]]['weight'] += 1
        else:
            G.add_edge(edge[0], edge[1], weight=1)
        G.nodes[edge[0]][label] = True
        G.nodes[edge[1]][label] = True

def keep_edges_with_weight_3(G):
    kept = []
    for u, v, weight in G.edges.data('weight'):
        if weight != 3:
            continue
        kept.append((u, v))
    return kept

def keep_edges_mine(G):
    kept = []
    for n, d in G.nodes(data=True):
        check = 0
        for label in "abc":
            if label in d:
                check += 1
        if check == 3:
            kept.append(n)
    print(kept)
    kept_edges = []
    for u, v, weight in G.edges.data('weight'):
        if u not in kept or v not in kept:
            continue
        kept_edges.append((u, v))
    return kept_edges

for i in range(2):
    first = not i % 2
    if first:
        a = [(2, 1), (3, 2), (9, 3), (10, 9), (11, 10)]
        b = [(2, 1), (3, 2), (9, 3), (10, 9), (11, 10)]
        c = [(2, 1), (3, 2), (10, 3), (11, 10), (1, 9)]
    else:
        a = [(2, 1), (3, 2), (9, 3), (10, 9), (11, 10), (50, 100)]
        b = [(2, 1), (3, 2), (9, 3), (10, 9), (11, 10), (50, 100)]
        c = [(2, 1), (3, 2), (10, 3), (11, 10), (1, 22), (50, 100)]
    G = nx.Graph()
    update_graph(G, a, 'a')
    update_graph(G, b, 'b')
    update_graph(G, c, 'c')
    edges_to_keep = keep_edges_mine(G)
    G2 = nx.Graph()
    update_graph(G2, edges_to_keep, 'final')
    clusters = get_final_clusters(G2)
    print(clusters)
```

Output, where the second graph solution does
not include 9, as it is not in list c:

```
{0: NodeView((2, 1, 3, 9, 10, 11))}
{0: NodeView((2, 1, 3, 10, 11)), 1: NodeView((50, 100))}
```

Comment: Hi, maybe you could have a look at my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

@VirtualScooter,

I tried your example with bigger examples and it did not give me desired results. I include the code which gives the desired results, but I am thinking if this could be optimised? In the original question I forgot to mention how a,b and c are derived, so I commented in the code below in my answer. The main idea is to collect clusters from individual graphs and then to look for every possible case for intersection and if the length is greater than 2, then append that to the accumulator of clusters. Once this is done we can find the final edges. The code below returns **{0: NodeView((1, 2, 3, 10, 11)), 1: NodeView((50, 100))}** , but is inefficient.

```
import networkx as nx

def build_graph(edges_set):
    G = nx.Graph()
    for edge in edges_set:
        G.add_edge(edge[0], edge[1], weight=1)

    return G


def get_final_clusters(graph):
    components = (graph.subgraph(c) for c in nx.connected_components(graph))
    comp_dict = {idx: comp.nodes() for idx, comp in enumerate(components)}

    return comp_dict

def get_intersections(connected_feature_1, connected_feature_2):
    intersections = []
    for nodes_set_first_feature in connected_feature_1:
        for nodes_set_second_feature in connected_feature_2:
            intersection = nodes_set_first_feature.intersection(nodes_set_second_feature)

            if len(intersection) > 1:
                intersections.append(intersection)

    return intersections


def get_edges_from_intersections(intersections):
    edges = []
    for intersection in intersections:
        list_intersection = list(intersection)
        for i in range(1, len(list_intersection)):
            edges.append((list_intersection[i - 1], list_intersection[i]))

    return edges

# a = list(nx.connected_components(g1))
# b = list(nx.connected_components(g2))
# c = list(nx.connected_components(g3))

a = [{1,2,3,9,10,11}, {50,100}]
b = [{1,2,3,9,10,11}, {50,100}]
c = [{1,2,3,10,11, 22}, {50,100}]


intersections = get_intersections(a, b)
edges_final = get_edges_from_intersections(get_intersections(intersections,
                                                              c))

g = build_graph(edges_final)
clusters = get_final_clusters(g)

print(clusters)
```